# Why does the width of div suddenly becomes 0 when positioned absolute?

Tags: html, css

consider the following:

```
<style>
 div{
  height: 100px; 
  background-color: red; 
  }
</style>
<body>
 <div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Now if I absolutely positioned the div, it suddenly disappears.

```
<style>
 div{
  height: 100px; 
  background-color: red; 
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  }
</style>
<body>
 <div>
 </div>
</body>
```

On inspecting, it shows the width to be zero. Why is that so?

Answer (score 2):

Because with absolute positioning, you are 100% in control of it's size and position. It's no longer a block vs. inline element because those terms relate to the element's size/position in the document flow, but when you position it absolutely, you take it out of the normal flow. Your `div` is empty, thus takes no screen space unless you declare it to.